# Making Content stay in one place with angularJS or angularUI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

How do I create collapsable columns in angular/angularui. So that my content doesn't move around depending on what resolution the screen is.

Comment: Positioning in CSS, namely absolute positioning.  Create a column, assign parent div to have absolute positioning.

Comment: Isn't absolute deprecated. I'm taking about using something within the angular framework the make it so if the browser is smaller all the items end up on top of each other.